# How to setup dynamic Subdomain in Yii 2

Tags: php, apache, yii, yii2, wildcard-subdomain

I am in need of dynamic subdomains to work. My current URL is

http://DOMAIN.com/con/view?id=1

I have a route that does this

```
'http://<id:\w+>.DOMAIN.com/' => 'con/view',
```

I also set up wildcard subdomains in my DNS settings. *.domain.com

Currently when going to my subdomain, it shows the sysdefault error message.

What am I missing?

I'm using Yii 2 for my project with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a question of yii2, This should be related to the apache configuration.

But I do not know much about apache.

In nginx, you should config a server as a default server, and then all request will be handled by this server. So it is a question about server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to setup a subdomain to point to a controller action, 
you have to add a rule in url manager like this

```
    'http://<w:\w+>.domain.com'=>'con/view',
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't do my markup right in the original question above, but in my original question I had a route that does this: 'http://<id:\w+>.DOMAIN.com/' => 'con/view',